# Am I performing properly an animation in WinApi?

Tags: c++, image, winapi, animation, gif

I have a small application that displays an animated GIF image. The GIF frames are saved as HBITMAPs. I perform the animation simply by setting a timer and using bitblt function when WM_TIMER event occurs in the window procedure. And although the timer is set to proper delay, my GIF animation is slightly slower than the animation of the same file in a browser. So the question is, if is there a better way than using a timer to do the job or the problem lies in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accuracy of WM_TIMER is determined by the Windows clock interrupt rate and the responsiveness of the UI thread.  The clock ticks by default 64 times per second, once every 15.625 milliseconds.  A timer will never be more accurate than that.  Or in other words, if you ask for, say, 10 msec then you won't get a WM_TIMER message until 15.625 msec have passed.  Similarly, if you ask for 16 msec then you won't get the message until 2 x 15.625 = 31.250 msec have passed.

The GIF format specifies animation times for a frame with a unit of 10 milliseconds.  So that by itself is already enough to make your animation take longer than intended.

You can change the WM_TIMER accuracy by calling timeBeginPeriod().  Asking for a period of 10 is the logical choice.  Call timeEndPeriod() when you're done.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I didn't know about this glitch. Still using timeBeginPeriod() is not helping, should I assume then that the timer is the correct approach and the problem lies in the code?

Comment: Of course, assuming it is an "operating system bug" never gets anybody anywhere.

Comment: I ignored your unfair comment before, but I have to answer now anyway because I've finally found out the solution. Unfair, because I've never thought or said that it could be an "operating system bug", the question was about if the approach is proper or not, asked to make myself sure whether I have to do some changes in the code or otherwise need to use another approach. And the answer was "no", because the timeBeginPeriod() function doesn't have an impact on a timer from the SetTimer() function, a multimedia timer (for ex. created by the CreateTimerQueueTimer() func) must be used instead.